# WPF - INSTALLSHIELD LE - Additional Files

Tags: wpf, installshield-le

I have the following situation:

- WPF Application
- I know about the different ways of deploying. (CAO, InstallShield, ..)
- Project includs some Report Files (.rdlc) which
  are used by calling them via Path - Right now in a Subdirectory of my PRojectfolder
- The Paths are defined in Settings

BUT:

I absolutely dont know how to handle this situation during and after Installation.

If I provide the rdlc files as additional files, how can I automatically change the path, after installation (so that the App can find them), because I dont know before the  path of the new client machine. Or do I misunderstood an the InstallShield is managing this files and paths automatically!

Can anybody help me with the right strategy (I am not looking for Code)!?!?
Thanky in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the installer, place the files relative to INSTALLDIR directory. INSTALLDIR can be modified by the user during installation. You may want to save the value in a registry or a configuration file. For registry, create the required hive and key and set its value to [INSTALLDIR]. For configuration file, you would need to write a custom action that modifies the file with the chosen INSTALLDIR.